# how to put a side navigation button above the side nav

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

can"t figure out how to put the side navigation open and close button and a search bar above the side navigation like in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7BOX.png)
I am using bootstrap 4 as my framework
the link to my source code is on https://github.com/B10NARY/sportsaholiclife
the link to what my code looks like online is http://www.sportsaholiclife.tk/
the server may be slow as it is in my home

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Are you asking how to add a toggle button so that whenever clicked, the sidebar will appear/disappear? Is that right?

Comment: the site isnt loading..fyi

Comment: yes i am trying got figure out how to make it when it is clicked it will disapear /apear and i want it at the top left hand corner like in the pic

Comment: @cameorngroves Could you please provide the code you have already tried?

Comment: the code should be on the git-hub link is it not?

Comment: It is. However, please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok thank @AjayGupta for the info i will take the in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it sticky and above all your other content, you can simply add margin to your entire body element and set your toggle button to a fixed position:

```
body {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#menu-toggle {
   position: fixed;
  left: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in comments, fixed position is not the best approach, so the other way will be to just add a simple wrapper div ontop of your layout and place a toggle button into it, no additional css rules required.

```
<body>
    <div class="p-2">
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="#menu-toggle" 
id="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
           ...
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/mkrl/pen/EdJYjz)

Comment: using fixed positioning will cause your layout to break in most of the cases if not used carefully. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227558/what-is-the-biggest-cons-to-use-position-absolute-top-left-over-float-margi)

Comment: @AjayGupta good point, I've updated my answer with a better approach.